# include <iostream> works in ViewController.h but not in appDelegate.h

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

So I am trying to move some C++ objects from my viewController.h and .mm to my appDelegate.h and .mm. Problem is I get a preprocessor issue stating that for example  can not be found, neither can string. I've tried to change file type to Objective-C++ header but still I get an error, if I try to #include  in the viewController.h I get no such error. How can i import c++ in the appDelegate?

```
//  AppDelegate.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <iostream> // <-"'iostream' file not found"


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

And the working case with viewController:

```
//  ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <iostream>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"AppDelegate.h" is also included from "main.m". Renaming that file to "main.mm" should solve
the problem.

If "iostream" is not required for the public interface "AppDelegate.h" you should
alternatively consider to include that file only in the implementation file "AppDelegate.mm",
that would also solve the problem.

Comment: @newacct: Thank you for fixing my C++ faux pas!